# Hardware configuration to connect local office network to internet wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 3g, sim

I don't know what response this question is going to get, I guess some people might think it's stupid but I've been searching the internet and I'm stumped so I'm turning to this community - I know if you guys on here can't help, then no one can.

Got into office this morning and our internet is down, phoned our ISP and it turns out that Vodaphone are very decently having a national outage...

My question is: is there any way I can quickly get the network back online - even temporarily - through wireless?  I've been searching to see if there's any kind of solution where I can plug a 3G / 4G enabled device into the network to get it back online, but I can't find anything.  Does anyone know if there is hardware I can buy that I can stick a SIM into it to connect to 4G and plug it into our network with an ethernet cable?  Or any configuration of hardware that would give the same effect?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Tom

Comment: Many SoHo routers have a USB port (or more) for the purpose of using 3G/4G modems and/or printers and/or other USB devices. Other than that a gateway server is required. It will handle the mobile connection as any other but if you don't have one, adding and configuring it will probably take longer than the outage. Of course you can use any PC with WiFi, typically a laptop, to create a hotspot, re-configure the router as bridge so that LAN clients can also make use of, but again, it may take longer than the outage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've since found out that there are several routers from small home routers to enterprise level that can be purchased with 3G and 4G capabilities, I've got one on order now so all good!  Some you can put a USB modem in, others, you can insert a SIM directly into the router.

Comment: Just FYI, this feature is not restricted to enterprise level routers, many home routers offer it, too. There are even ISPs (at least here in Germany) who offer DSL with fallover 3G/4G service for home users as part of a basic contract.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I made it sound like only Enterprise level routers had this feature.  I'll amend the answer to make it clearer.